# Get sum of elements dynamic class name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, class, dynamic

I am working on a table that adds rows at the press of a button. Within the new row,  elements class names are dependent on the selection of a drop-down menu. The classes are named like so:

```
 let newRow = <tr><td class='fuel "+ACID+"'></td></tr>
```

where ACID is the ID of the selected index of a drop-down menu on the main HTML page.

I am trying to write a function that calculates sums of every element with a particular class name. Here is what I have:

```
const ACID = [Array of all possible ACID values];
let k = 0;
let ac_fuel = 0;
    ACID.forEach(element => {
        $('.fuel '+ACID[k]).each(function() {
            ac_fuel += parseFloat($(this).html());
            console.log(ac_fuel);
        })      
    k++
```

The problem is that this gets the sum of every .fuel.ACID[k] together. I want to have separate sums for every class. I have included a screenshot (link at bottom) that includes some notes, console logs, and the table itself. I've also included a GitHub repository with all the files: https://github.com/GregoryAESO/EmissionsCalculator/tree/gh-pages/Emissions%20Calculator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map function for ACID array. Map function iterate throug all the array values using element variable and return an array with the same elements count, but modified, e.g.:
Also please note that selecting elements with 2 classes should be performed using selector `classA.classB` whitespaces between classNames should not be used

```js
let ACID = ['T34', 'T454', 'AV8Bplus', 'AV8B', '']

const result = ACID.map(element => {
    let sum = 0;
    let collection;
    if(element ==='')
    {
      collection = $('.fuel')
            .filter(function(index){
                return $(this).attr("class").trim() == "fuel";
              })
    } else {
      collection = $('.fuel.'+element)
    }
  
    collection.each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).html());
    })  
  return {id: element, sum}
  })  
  
  console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = 'fuel T34'>15</div>
<div class = 'fuel T454'>33</div>
<div class = 'fuel AV8Bplus'>28</div>
<div class = 'fuel AV8B'>15</div>
<div class = 'fuel T34'>15</div>
<div class = 'fuel'>77</div>
```

It will return an array of sums for every ACID element. To further modification you can return for example an object, including ACID value: e.g. replace `return sum` with `return {id: element, sum}` which will return an array of object which looks like:

```
[{id: 'id1', sum: 15},{id: 'id2', sum: 0} ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm currently Trying to work with this function. The problem is this code just returns the sum of all of the elements with ACID value, and puts it at the bottom of the array: `18: {id: "T34", sum: 0}
19: {id: "T45", sum: 0}
20: {id: "MQ4C", sum: 0}
21: {id: "AH1W", sum: 0}
22: {id: "H1N", sum: 0}
23: {id: "H3H", sum: 0}
24: {id: "H3A", sum: 0}
25: {id: "H46D", sum: 0}
26: {id: "H53E", sum: 0}
27: {id: "H60", sum: 0}
28: {id: "H71", sum: 0}
29: {id: "AV8B", sum: 0}
30: {id: "AV8Bplus", sum: 0}
31: {id: "V22", sum: 0}
32: {id: "", sum: 3526.22}`

Comment: @gbiz123 so could you please add expected output

Comment: the expected output would be something like: `18: {id: "T34", sum: 310} 19: {id: "T45", sum: 902} 20: {id: "MQ4C", sum: 0} 21: {id: "AH1W", sum: 123} 22: {id: "H1N", sum: 760}`, so I have a sum for every ID

Comment: got the problem. The problem is selectingelements by classes, classes in DOM elements are separated with ' ' whitespace, and selector for both classes should not be written as `.classA classB` (whitespace between classes) it should be written as `.classA.classB` (dot between classes). Modified answer with snippet @gbiz123

Comment: I really appreciate the help! unfortunately I am having another error: `caught (in promise) Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .fuel.`. It doesn't seem to know what I mean by .fuel.

Comment: the td element I am trying to find the sum of is made like this: `<td class='fuel "+ACID+"' >`

Comment: @gbiz123 so I assume in your ACID array you alo have '' - empty string, and need the total sum here or sum of elements with only 1 class? if my assumption is correct inside map function additional check is needed

Comment: Ah , I see. I was able to get it to work using native javascript instead of jquery: `let object = document.getElementsByClassName('fuel '+element);
  $(object).each(function() { ...`

Comment: @gbiz123 it was an interesting quest. I'm glad it's solved!